# Converting int array to String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

Hello i want to convert int Array into Required Format.

i have int array and how to convert it ?
i want this String format

```
int a = [1,2,3,4]
list a = [1,2,3,4]
String = ["1","2","3"];
```

Comment: I know lots of answers on the way, but what you have tried so far ? `Hint : String.valuOf(intValue);`

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a question. The answer to your question is the top answer for "java array to string" on Google.

Comment: @TwoThe i have tried okey and was not getting ans that is why i out that.

Comment: Ya i have tried. @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: From next time on words do not forget to add tried code. Anyways you have multiple answers and duplicated questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `int[]` and convert to `String[]`.

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
String[] convertedArr = new String[a.length];
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  convertedArr[i] = String.valueOf(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Its not working its giving String formate like this.@88174c i need String values..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String res = Arrays.toString(a).replaceAll("(\\d+)", "\"$1\"")
```

Comment: its not working dude its giving still that complex Structure i dont want it.